# Порядок действий при создании отношения один-ко-многим в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу понять, как это делать правильно, ибо в phpmyadmin новых полей не добавляется. Имеется две модели - products и categories
файл миграции для products

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->text('des');
            $table->foreign('category')->on('categories')->references('name');
        });
    }
```

categories

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->string('name');
        });
    }
```

Comment: А как Вы это делали? Чтобы добавились новые поля в БД, нужно добавить их в миграцию. А порядок действий можно и поискать, прежде чем писать сюда: [one to many relationships example laravel](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=one+to+many+relationships+example+laravel)

Comment: в файле миграции поле для связи есть, есть даже функции в классах, но поля - нет, пишу php artisan migrate - Nothing to migrate.

Comment: По текстовому описанию Вашей проблемы, тяжело что-то сказать, я не вижу Вашего кода. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: сейчас добавлю код

Comment: всё, добавил код

Comment: А какова задумка в целом? Один продукт может иметь множество категорий? А Вы уверены что для продуктов и категорий нужно отнешение one to many, а не many to many? Вроде как это логичнее. У продукта может быть множество категорий, как и у категории может быть множество продуктов. Странновато делать уникальные категории для каждого продукта.

Comment: точно, неправильную связь выбрал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов для привязки двух таблиц, в миграции на `laravel`.

Вот первый метод.

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->text('des');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

А вот второй вариант.

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('category_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->text('des');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Как то не понятно зачем привязать таблицы с колонкой `name` ?

Привязка таблиц делается числевыми колонками.

Посмотри более подробно в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId).

Ну а если хочешь что бы к одному продукту можно было привязать несколько категорий, тебе понадобиться еще одна таблица (`product_categories`).

**1. Products**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->text('des');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**2. Categories**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**3. Product Categories**

```
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: `$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');` даст ошибку, $table->foreignId('category_id') = 8 bit biginteger, $table->increments('id') = 4 bit biginteger. А вариантов с привязкой больше, я обычно полностью расписываю чтобы читабельный вар-т был, аля `$table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');`

Comment: @InDevX можно и так.